# Make footer the last div on the page

Tags: html, css, footer, adsense

My copyright footer is the last unit in the HTML and should always be at the bottom.  However, Google's "auto ads" javascript sometimes doesn't act very intelligently and injects an ad unit below the copyright footer, which is unsightly and looks silly.  How do I ensure that the footer is the last div on the page?

Comment: hope you are giving space for google to add their ads? can you give me your sample html structure?

Comment: Plenty of room for ads.  They started appearing below the copyright after I removed sticky footer code, which was creating too many conflicts with other elements.  The page is still being written, nothing concrete.

Comment: Yo can reserve space for adds with fixed height and width. Can yo give me ur css for adds wrapper

Comment: This is auto ads.  I don't specify any wrappers.  They appear wherever the site's code allows them to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Generally auto ads are very good at identifying specific parts of your website such as header, footer and sidebar.

However, depending on what CMS your are using and the CSS naming used on your site to designate individual parts of your site, Auto Ads sometimes gets it wrong.

To better guide AdSense Auto Ads to not show under your footer div, make sure that your footer div/css clearly identifies your footer as the footer. ie. label your footer clearly, as well as all other links inside your html.

In my experience this has almost always solved the problem once Auto Ads is given 1-2 weeks to 'learn'.